# Consuming JSON stream in Spring Boot 3.2

Tags: java, json, spring

I want to consuming a JSON stream that is being sent to me from a remote server. I am in Java & Spring Boot environment. I want to compare the plane registration field for a match.

I have setup a controller in Spring Boot to do this and want to know if there is a valid approach:

**JSON**

```
{
     "Plane Rego":"N3834Y",
     "Departrure":"LAX",
     "Destination":"HNY"
 }
```

The JSON is sent from the remote server at a interval of about 1/second and the controller looks to match a single hard coded airplane registration N3834Y. This is my attempt so far (working, but I think missing some registrations):

```
@RestController
public class PlaneController {
    public PlaneController() {
    }

    @PostMapping(
    value = "/planealerts")
    public Plane acceptPlane(@RequestBody Plane plane, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(plane.getPlaneReg() + " " + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
        if (plane.getPlaneReg().equals("N3834Y")) {
            System.out.println("Plane departed : " + plane.getPlaneReg().toString());
            // other stuff
        return plate;
    }
}
```

There is no requirement to write anything to a database, just scan the incoming JSON for a match on the single plane registration. There is java class for the plane JSON which I can post if necessary.

The question is if there is anything wrong with the approach that might cause plane registrations to be silently missed? (For such a simple case I am not using a service)

Hopefully this is not too opinionated for SO Q format.

Comment: "I think missing some registrations" why do you think this?